# Eating keys in WM_SYSKEYDOWN

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I need to handle the WM_SYSKEYDOWN Message sent to my window when alt or F10 is pressed and so I did this in pretranslatemessage for my window

I checked for MSG parameter's message to WM_SYSKEYDOWN and returned true, it is some thing similar to this

```
BOOL Class::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    MSG *pMessage = (MSG *)pMsg;
    HWND hwnd = ::GetActiveWindow();
    if(::IsWindowEnabled(hwnd)==NULL){
        if(pMsg->message = WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
    return true;
    }
    }
    return parentclass::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

But this function is not triggered when the user presses the alt key.

I verified in spy++ that when user clicked alt key a WM_SYSKEYDOWN message is sent to the window for which I wrote pretranslatemessage.

I am able to resolve the issue by writing a message handler

```
void Class::OnSysKeyDown(UINT nChar,UINT nRepCnt,UINT nFlags)
{
    HWND hwnd = ::GetActiveWindow();
    if(::IsWindowEnabled(hwnd)==NULL){
        return;
    }
    parentclass::OnSysKeyDown(nChar,nRepCnt,nFlags);
}
```

and including ON_WM_SYSKEYDOWN in Message Map

Comment: Is it necessary to point out that Pretransaltemessage() is spelled wrong?  It probably is, a C++ compiler doesn't blink when you throw gobbledegook at it like this.  It blindly assumes that you created a new virtual method, you didn't override PreTranslateMessage().    The C++11 *override* keyword was overdue.  -1 for posting garbage code that cannot possibly compile.

Comment: sorry about that I typed it by mistake

Comment: Sigh, it is still nonsense code that cannot compile.  And you still got the spelling wrong.  Why on Earth are you not copy/pasting the code you used in your program???

Comment: The check for IsWindowEnabled is written wrongly. The function returns BOOL non-zero if the window is enabled. NULL signifies a null pointer and should not be used for this purpose.

Comment: PreTranslate is not WinApi. Is this MFC or ATL or what? Is the problem just sloppy coding?

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit curious after I saw your post, so I did a quick test, and as expected WM_SYSKEYDOWN certainly does get sent on Alt-F10 combination (since that message is specifically intended for Alt-Key combinations).  In fact, you will get 4 messages which result in the following:

```
   Message       Key    Char      Repeat    Scan   Ext   Alt   Prev   Tran
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_SYSKEYDOWN     18    Alt         1        56     No   Yes    Up    Down
WM_SYSKEYDOWN    121    F10         1        68     No   Yes    Up    Down
 WM_SYSKEYUP     121    F10         1        68     No   Yes   Down    Up
 WM_SYSKEYUP      18    Alt         1        56     No    No   Down    Up
```

So double check your code, and I am sure you will determine the issue.  I hope this helps!